# How to fail on executing zero byte file?

Tags: executable, exit-status

If I have zero byte file and it is executable, it will just do nothing. Can I fail on such files, i.e. return some error message and/or return non-zero exit code?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, zero byte file is a valid  shell script.

Comment: ... but you *can* check its size before executing it and fail if the size is 0.

Comment: An empty executable file is a valid implementation of the `true` command.  Do you want `sh -c ''` to return an error message or a non-zero exit code as well?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: No. Trying to execute a zero size executable will fail with ENOEXEC.What you're seeing is a feature of your shell or utility, which will try to run an executable by passing it to /bin/sh (or interpreting it itself) in case of ENOEXEC. Of course, you're not telling what system, shell or utility you're using, and what exactly your problem is, because facts and details are too boring.

Comment: What is the use-case? Knowing this may help us give a better answer.

Comment: @UncleBilly I am omitting "facts and details" because I don't want answerers to de-focus themselves from the topic :D

Answer (score 1):

So, I think the only answer answer is

```
if [ -s mybinary ]
then
   mybinary
else
   exit 1
fi
```

right?

Comment: what difference does it make if the file is empty or contains just a newline, a zero byte, a comment line or multiple newlines, etc?

Comment: you are right, hence the answer is incorrect